# df show wrong output

Tags: hard-drive, df

My `df -h` output:

```
root@haier-ubuntu:/# df -h
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/haier--ubuntu-root  457G  433G  691M 100% /
none                            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs                           385M  1.1M  384M   1% /run
none                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                            1.9G  7.0M  1.9G   1% /run/shm
none                            100M  8.0K  100M   1% /run/user
overflow                        1.0M  4.0K 1020K   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                       228M   88M  129M  41% /boot
```

See the line `/dev/mapper/haier--ubuntu-root  457G  433G  691M 100% /`, `Used + Avail != Size` and `(Used / Size) * 100% != Use%`.
What is wrong?

***Update:***

I think this question is different from [What is the difference between du -h and ls -lh?](https://serverfault.com/questions/290088/what-is-the-difference-between-du-h-and-ls-lh). The reason that `du -h` and `ls -lh` show different results is due to so called `slack space`. But my question is about `reserved space`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between du -h and ls -lh?](http://serverfault.com/questions/290088/what-is-the-difference-between-du-h-and-ls-lh)

Comment: See for instance http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why

Comment: @HBruijn Thanks. This link tell me why there is reserved space in linux filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most filesystems have some diskspace reserved for journaling, defragmentation, caching etc. Usually that is 5-10% of raw capacity.