# du -sh * show significant more used space that ls -lah

Tags: mysql, database, disk-space-utilization, ls, du

I am having trouble with running out of diskspace of one of my clients servers.

The output of the commands `ls -lah` in `/var/lib/mysql` shows:

```
drwx------  2 mysql mysql  16K Dec 30  2015 database_xyz
```

But when I check the filesize in the same catalogue with the command `du -sh *`, the output shows:

```
22G     database_xyz
```

Why does the output of thoose commands shows two completely different results?

I have only 2.2GB left on the drive.

```
root@jon-cust-lifeincity:/var/lib/mysql# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root    49G   44G  2.2G  96% /
tmpfs                1007M     0 1007M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                 1002M  108K 1002M   1% /dev
tmpfs                1007M     0 1007M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             228M   16M  200M   8% /boot
```

EDIT:

Turns out that `database_xyz` is in fact a catalogue, not a file. So the confusion was made up by my brain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between du -h and ls -lh?](http://serverfault.com/questions/290088/what-is-the-difference-between-du-h-and-ls-lh)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you have a misunderstanding about what you are being told. The `ls -lah` command lists the contents of the current directory. In this particular case that's  `/var/lib/mysql`. Amongst other things you were told this

```
drwx------  2 mysql mysql  16K Dec 30  2015 database_xyz
```

You are misunderstanding what this is telling you.

You can consider a directory to be like a flat file containing a list of directory entries. (simply) A directory entry is a file name and a pointer to where that file resides on disk. This information takes up disk space.

What

```
drwx------  2 mysql mysql  16K Dec 30  2015 database_xyz
```

is telling you is that there is a directory entry in `/var/lib/mysql` called `database.xyz`. That entry is for a file type `d` which indicates it is a directory and amongst other things the size of the directory 'file'  is 16K.

Comment: Yes,,, I just found out that the database_xyz is a directory, not a file...

Comment: A directory is nothing more that a file with a listing of the files inside it. This directory listing file has thus a filesize. You can see the file by using `vi database_xyz` if the directoryname is database_xyz.

Comment: @SPRBRN I don't think that's quite correct. I think vi recognises that it's a directory and treats it in a 'special' manner. Take a look at https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Directory_Entries and then try to 'cat' or more a directory file and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

To know the size of **database_xyz** file only just type

```
du -sh database_xyz
```

you will find the exact result

Comment: Yes,,, I just found out that the database_xyz is a directory, not a file...

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is not the right tool to find directory size. It works only for files not directories.

I can see that you are listing details of a directory (the first `d` char)

```
drwx------  2 mysql mysql  16K Dec 30  2015 database_xyz
```

Use `du` instead. This is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1019116/471547) at stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes,,, I just found out that the database_xyz is a directory, not a file...